# How to organize HTML snippets within a Flask app

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2, organization

Within my Flask app, I have several elements (buttons and the like) that I want to use across different templates. Copying in the HTML code each time seems tedious, but adding a specific HTML file for every element to include also seems excessive. I'll end up with a large templates directory.

Is there a better way of doing this? I thought about creating a macros.html file and then importing each one of those every time.

I guess the other way to do it would be to create a filter for each type and register that within my app. (app.template_filter)

What is the best way to organize these elements?

Comment: Does it have to be Jinja? I personally stopped using template engines. I use python functions and the yattag library for my html templates. This is more flexible.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions on the best approach. I'm using Flask as my framework, and it has jinja2 built in, so it is what I have been using so far. But it is early days yet for this app, things can be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a template for the subset of the HTML code you think you are going to re-use a lot and then include them in your other HTML file using the [jinja construct {% include ... %}](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#include)

For example:

You can have the `<head>` tag and the navigation menu of your website (if your site does use one) in a header template file. Let us call it `tl_header.html` You can have the footer related HTML in another file `tl_footer.html`. Now for every other page on your site you can create the HTML file like:

```
{% include tl_header.html %}
...
page specific HTML
...
{% include tl_footer.html %}
```

I hoe this gave you an idea how to extract common HTML elements into a separate template and including them in other templates. Makes code more maintainable.

Comment: should be like `{% include 'tl_footer.html' %}`, with quotations.